# Unable to register AWS host to Ambari server

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

While registering a host to the cluster of Ambari-server, I am getting the following error.
"**Host checks were skipped on 1 hosts that failed to register**."
I'm trying to install HDP 2.5 version on the instance of AWS.

I have tried to follow the documentation of Hortonworks.
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-installation/content/set_the_hostname.html

I have added public ip address and public hostname to /etc/hosts file and change the name of host in /etc/hostname file on the server and on the host. Rebooted both, hostname got changed. Then I have stop iptables by

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

After doing everything, the host registration is still failing. Kindly help. I am stuck.

Comment: Why such an old version of HDP? And why not use Cloudbreak or just use Amazon EMR?

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

From my experience with Ambari (Hortonworks) you have to explicitly setup your Hadoop nodes in each other's `/etc/hosts` file with the actual name/IPs that the Hadoop services will bind to. **NOTE:** hostnames should also be FQDN - fully qualified domain names.

For example if you're setting up the hosts as:

- node01.mydom.com (10.0.0.2)
- node02.mydom.com (10.0.0.3)
- node03.mydom.com (10.0.0.4)

These entries should be in all 3 server's `/etc/hosts` and these should be the names used when referencing them within Ambari's installation/setup wizards.

If you do not pay special attention to this detail, Ambari's server will fail to find/manage any of the other node's that you're telling it to manage.

#### hostname of ambari-agents

The other item to look at is that the ambari-agent's and what hostnames they think they're going as.

```
$ ps -eaf|grep ambari_agent
root      3282     1  0 Jul30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/AmbariAgent.py start --expected-hostname=node01.mydom.com
root      3290  3282  1 Jul30 ?        08:24:29 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py start --expected-hostname=node01.mydom.com
```

#### Debugging further

In the screen where you're attempting to register the other nodes as agents, there's a full log of what's happening and you can typically get the commands from this area and attempt to run them directly. I've done this on a number of occasions. The commands will often be `python ...` commands which you can then copy/paste from the logs and run on the Ambari server where you're attempting to run the install.

Comment: If you have to manually configure your hosts file, then you have a poor (or no) DNS implementation, which is not Ambari's or HDP's responsibility to configure

Comment: @cricket_007 - I've set it up w/ and w/o physical DNS for Hadoop. It can be done, but is simpler to get the names/IPs squared away via `/etc/hosts`, IMO. I've set up 100's of Hadoop/HBase clusters in various sizes from docker container, to single node, to 6+ node.

Comment: Maybe if you can automate that file with Puppet/Ansible, sure. But I'd rather not have to update every single server every time you double the cluster size.

Comment: @cricket_007 - agreed. That's exactly what I do via Ansible. I took Deya as new to Hadoop and was getting him bootstrapped to start.

Comment: Yeah, though if new to Hadoop, setting up HDP manually is probably not the best way to get started when EMR and Cloudbreak are purposely designed to deploy in AWS

Comment: @cricket_007 - it depends. Working through the setup I find helpful with learning how everything goes together and works. If you're just trying to use it for real work, then I agree.